# Model can not be created by FactoryGirl

Tags: ruby-on-rails, factory-bot, rspec-rails, ruby-datamapper

I have three models A, B and C where model of C which is in DataMapper is as follows:

```
Class C do
   include DataMapper::Resource
   belongs_to :A, :key=>true
   belongs_to :B, :key=>true
end
```

I have specified this in FactoryGirl like this:

```
factory :c do |c|
   c.association :a
   c.association :b
end
```

I have created model C in my spec file as follows:

```
@c = FactoryGirl.create(:c)
```

But it is giving the following error.

```
 NoMethodError:
   undefined method `name' for 465:Fixnum
```

Cannot I create C as it has no property id? So I am looking for help to fix this problem.

Comment: `Class C do` check the syntax is it right?

Comment: can you please post the actual factories for c a and b ? make sure you have defined factories for both `a` and `b` before creating the factory for `c`. when you create `c` it creates both `a` and `b` because of the association

Comment: Maybe the problem is in `a` or `b` factories.